# How to subscribe to two topics in ROS in a good way (image and bounding boxes are published separately)

Tags: c++, ros

I am currently building a ROS node for object detection. 
It follows the following pipeline:

1. The image is published
2. The published image is subscribed by a neural network node, which runs an object detection on it and then publishes a list of bounding boxes.
3. Now I would like to subscribe to both topics and perform a template matching on the detected bounding boxes. Then the result is published.

The problem is that the image is published before the bounding box and I need to put them back together.

My first idea would be something like [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/12421/subscribing-2-topics-of-different-types-in-a-callback-function/), but the images are published much more often than the NN outputs the bounding box, so they don't fit together. Also, I have four cameras publishing on the same topic so I would need to also include the frame id.

The second idea would be to publish one message with image and bounding box. This would probably be the cleanest version, but I am not sure how to do that with the image_transport method.

I am using this implementation of darknet for ROS:
https://github.com/leggedrobotics/darknet_ros

Could somebody help me out, how to properly implement a safe and reliable way to publish the images with the bounding boxes in one message?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[message_filter](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters) package in ROS can achieve what you want.

Similar to initializing a subscriber, you create a message filter subscriber which can accept multiple messages from different topics. message filter callback function provides you the best matched messages from each topic together. You can chose ExactTime policy to match messages with same timestamps or ApproximateTime policy where an adaptive algorithm is used to match messages with closest timestamps.

In your case, I would use ApproximateTime policy to match your low-frequency detection with closest timestamped high-frequency image.